# Spring Boot export SQL from in-memory DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I need to export the whole in-memory db to an sql file. For e.g to make a @Controller which returns a the whole SQL generation string of the current in-mem db state, or to save it somewhere on the disk.

Configuration:

- Spring Boot 1.8
- Spring Data JPA 1.7
- Hibernate 4.3.6
- HSQLDB 2.3.2

I've tried to find a way to export the data - the schema and all the rows - but I was unsuccessful. 
In articles like this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-generate-schema-creation the Ejb3Configuration is removed from hibernate, so the method described is not working.

Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using HSQLDB you can use its [`SCRIPT` command](http://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/guide/ch09.html#script-section). If you just call `SCRIPT` it'll return a result set containing the database's schema. You can also pass in the path to a file and it'll dump the entire database to that file. For exampl `SCRIPT '/path/to/dump.sql'`. As you want the schema and all of the rows you should use the latter. Note that the command will fail if the file already exists.

As you're using Spring Boot an easy way to execute the `SCRIPT` command is by using `JdbcTemplate`. By default, if your application has a `DataSource` then a `JdbcTemplate` instance is automatically available in your application context.

A `@Controller` that triggers a dump of the database:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class DumpDbController {

    private final Object monitor = new Object();

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DumpDbController(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/dumpDb")
    @ResponseBody
    public void dumpDb() throws IOException {
        synchronized (this.monitor) {
            File dump = new File("dump.sql");
            if (dump.exists()) {
                dump.delete();
            }
            this.jdbcTemplate.execute("script '" + dump.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of synchronisation to ensure the multiple threads don't attempt to dump the database at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/index.html). This utility has methods which can generate the script you need but I think you must work on its API to archive this.

It has a [command line](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) utility which you can investigate how integrate with it. Also, there is a [Integration tool with spring](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html) but this is not what you need.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm suggesting you to use it as a library, using its API on your application runtime to generate the sql script as do the command line utility.